# I have a question regarding the multi-threaded file transfer program

Tags: c, multithreading, file

I am studying Multithread while making a file transfer program.

**Client Code(The code that sends the file)**

```
// Opened a file using fopen function.
int SendPercent = 0; // Value that shows the current progress
while (1)
    {
        len = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZE, fp);
        if (len)
        {

            retval = send(sock, buf, len, 0);
            if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                err_display("send()");
                break;
            }

            SendPercent += len;
            printf("percent : %2.2f%%\r", (float)SendPercent / (float)AllLen * 100.0f);
        }
        else if (SendPercent == AllLen)
        {
            printf("\nFinished.\n");
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("\nIt did not end successfully.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
```

**Server Code(The code that receives the file)**

```
        FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "wb");

        while (1)
        {
            retval = recv(client_sock, buf, sizeof(buf), MSG_WAITALL);
            if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                err_display("recv()");
                break;
            }
            else if (retval == 0) {
                printf("\ncurLen : %f, allLen : %f\n", (float)curLen, (float)allLen);
                break;
            }
            curLen += fwrite(buf, 1, retval, fp);
            memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
            printf("percent : %2.2f%%\r", (float)curLen / (float)allLen * 100.0f);
            if (curLen == allLen)
            {
                printf("\nSuccessfully Received.\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

The server's receive function acts as multi-threaded through the CreateThread function.
It works fine when sending small files of 4KB size, but problems arise when sending large files of more than 77000KB.

**When a problem occurs(server)**

```
percent : 99.92%
curLen : 79141464.000000, allLen : 79202368.000000
[TCP Server] Disconnected. IP Address=127.0.0.1, Port Number=....
```

**When a problem occurs(client)**

```
percent : 100.00%
Finished.
```

The client disconnects before the curLen reaches allLen.
What's even more strange is that when I open a folder in the server program and look at the received files, the files have been copied successfully.
Is the file sent correctly?
Why isn't the server's transmission rate going up properly?
Obviously, this program worked normally when it was single thread.
Sadly, I have not even identified the cause of the problem before solving this problem. Please help me.

Comment: Maybe you need to flush the output stream from client before disconnecting?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a [mre]. What are the types of the variables? What is the size of `buf`? Where does `allLen` come from? Maybe try without `MSG_WAITALL`. BTW: Why do you print `curLen` and `allLen` as floating point values when only integer values are possible?

Comment: The size of the buf is set by the BUFSIZE variable, and the size of the buf for both the client and the server is 512. And allLen is the size of the file to be transferred.
Before transferring the file, the client reads the size of the file and sends it to the server, which receives the value and stores it in allLen.

Comment: I have tried removing MSG_WAITALL tag from Recv, but the problem has not been solved.  Lastly, I cast curLen and allLen as float and printed it out because I wanted to see a more accurate state.  To explain the types of variables, retval and curLen, allLen are int types, buf is char[BUFSIZE], and client_sock is SOCKET types. The client code also specified the type of variable in the same way.

Comment: Don't use `%f` when printing integer values (just when showing percentage). _That_ is more accurate than using float. Note that printing progress/percentage messages can slow things down if they occur too frequently. The `stdout` stream gets backed up and prevents the program from proceeding until the messages come out. I usually limit this by only outputting them periodically (based on time) at (e.g.) 1 second intervals. Unless the `stdout` stream is unbuffered, you should do `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf` for percentage.

Comment: Does the flush of the output stream mean emptying the transmit buffer of the client program?

Comment: Correct. Winsock has a shutdown() function which I think will perform a flush https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-shutdown